# Theorem 1.24 Rudin, Functional analysis (first half)

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

Reading through theorem 1.24 of Rudin functional analysis. I'm struggling to understand a bit the construction of the metric, and related properties. Rudin defines $D$ as the set of all rational of the form

$$
r = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} c_n(r)2^{-r}
$$

where $c_i(r)$ is either $0$ or $1$ with finite many $1$. Now after defining

$$
A(r) = c_1(r) V_1 + c_2(r)V_2 + \ldots
$$

we have the definition of the functional

$$
f(x) = \inf \left\{r : x \in A(r) \right\}\;\;,x \in X
$$

(Here $X$ is a t.v.s. with a countable local base), it firstly assumes

$$
A(r)+A(s)\subset A(r+s)
$$

before actually proving it, it is also easy to proove

$$
A(r) < A(t) \Leftrightarrow r < t
$$
and now the first claim that puzzles me, I'm sure it is silly but still I struggle to understand. He proves

$$
f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y),
$$
And the first thing said is

> We may, of course, assume the right side is $< 1$

My first question is "why?". Right after

> Fix $\epsilon>0$. There exists $r$ and $s$ in $D$ such that $$ f(x)<r,f(y)<s, r+s<f(x)+f(y)+\epsilon$$

I know this might sound silly now but I can understand why I can find $r,s$ such that $f(x)<r$ and $f(y)<s$, which is independent from $\epsilon$ (this follows from the definition of $f$) but why the can I also have $r+s<f(x)+f(y)+\epsilon$?

And later it is stated

> If $x \neq 0$ then $x \notin V_n = A(2^{-n})$ for some $n$

While I have the intuition for this I struggle to prove this small step. And finally it is concluded the translation invariance of the metric $f$, I can get the "metric" but not the invariance....

Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

We can assume that the right hand side is $< 1$ since otherwise the inequality is trivially satisfied because $f(z) \leqslant 1$ for all $z$. So if $f(x) + f(y) \geqslant 1$, we have

$$f(x+y) \leqslant 1 \leqslant f(x) + f(y)\,.$$

Only for $f(x) + f(y) < 1$ is some work required to prove $f(x+y) \leqslant f(x) + f(y)$.

For the next problem, one cannot (usually) - and need not - find $r,s$ independent of $\epsilon$, the choice is made depending on $\epsilon$. Given any $\epsilon > 0$, by definition of $f$, namely $f(x) = \inf\:\{r : x \in A(r)\}$, we can find $r = r(\epsilon)$ such that $x \in A(r)$ and $r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$, and we can find $s = s(\epsilon)$ such that $y \in A(s)$ and $s < f(y) + \epsilon/2$. Then

$$x + y \in A(r) + A(s) \subset A(r+s)$$

whence $f(x+y) \leqslant r+s < f(x) + f(y) + \epsilon$. That $r$ and $s$ were chosen depending on $\epsilon$ is irrelevant, we just care about $f(x+y)$ and bounding that by $f(x) + f(y)$. Since
$$f(x+y) < f(x) + f(y) + \epsilon$$
holds for every $\epsilon > 0$, the desired inequality $f(x+y) \leqslant f(x) + f(y)$ follows.

The family $\{ V_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is by assumption a neighbourhood base of $0$ in $X$. Since $X$ is $T_1$ (part of the definition of a TVS in Rudin's book), for every $x \neq 0$ there is a neighbourhood $W_x$ of $0$ that doesn't contain $x$. By definition of a neighbourhood base, there is an $n$ such that $V_n \subset W_x$. For this $n$ (and all larger) we thus have $x \notin V_n$.

A metric $\rho$ on $X$ is translation-invariant if for all $x,y,z \in X$ we have

$$\rho(x+z,y+z) = \rho(x,y)\,. \tag{$\ast$}$$

The metric $d$ is defined by $d(x,y) = f(x-y)$, and from $(x+z) - (y+z) = x-y$ we thus obtain the translation-invariance of $d$:

$$d(x+z,y+z) = f\bigl((x+z) - (y+z)\bigr) = f(x-y) = d(x,y)\,,$$

whatever $x,y,z \in X$ are.

Comment: Hi, how do you use the definition to prove for example that $f(x) < r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$?

Comment: That's how we choose $r$, not something to prove. (Although I haven't imposed a strict inequality for the lower bound, we don't need that. Choosing $r$ such that $f(x) \leqslant r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$ works well. But if one wants an $r$ satisfying $f(x) < r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$ that's no problem either. We can explicitly choose $r = f(x) + \epsilon/4$ for example.) What may need proof is that such an $r$ exists. That follows from the definition of $f$, namely $f(x) = \inf \:\{ s > 0 : x \in A(s)\}$, and the definition of $\inf$. (Plus, if we insist on $f(x) < r$ the fact that

Comment: $s < t \implies A(s) \subset A(t)$.) By definition of $\inf$, $f(x) + \epsilon/2$ is not a lower bound of the set $\{s > 0 : x \in A(s)\}$. That means there is an $r$, $0 < r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$ such that $x \in A(r)$. On the other hand, $f(x)$ is a lower bound for the aforementioned set, so $f(x) \leqslant r$, together $f(x) \leqslant r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$.

Comment: I'm missing the bit $r \in D$, I get I can find $r \in D$ such that $f(x) < r$, among those how do get that there's some $r$ such that $r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$? Your explanation to me makes sense if we assume $r$ is real in general, which is not the case.

Comment: I forgot that Rudin didn't define $A(r)$ for all $r \in (0,+\infty)$ (by $$A(s) = \bigcup_{\substack{r \in D \\ r \leqslant s}} A(r)$$ typically). So we can't necessarily take $f(x) + \epsilon/4$, but we can find an $r \in D$ as close to that as we like, in particular one satisfying $f(x) < r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$. Well, at least for $f(x) < 1$; if we have $f(x) = 1$, then $r = 1$ is the only eligible member of $D$. But as I said, we don't need $f(x) < r$, we just need $f(x) \leqslant r$, which is automatic.

Comment: You lost me now, I think I'm fine with the $f(x) \leq r$, by definition of $f$. It's $r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$ I don't get.

Comment: Define $S(x) = \{ r \in D : x \in A(r)\}$. Then by definition $f(x)$ is the greatest lower bound of $S(x)$. Since $f(x) + \epsilon/2 > f(x)$, it follows that $f(x) + \epsilon/2$ is not a lower bound for $S(x)$, which means that $S(x) \cap [0, f(x) + \epsilon/2) = \{ r \in S(x) : r < f(x) + \epsilon/2\} \neq \varnothing$. Then take $r \in \{ r \in S(x) : r < f(x) + \epsilon/2\} $.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79698/discussion-between-user8469759-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: I've been away for dinner. It seems not all is yet clear?

Comment: I'll read again through your comments and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi again, I read through your last comment. I understand that your point is that the inequality $0 \leq r < f(x) + \epsilon/2$ has solution. Now, again, it is intuitive to me that if $r$ where considered real, the inequality has solution, if we restrict $r$ to be rational the inequality would still have solution, But what I'm missing is the further restriction to the rationals that Rudin gives. Is it possible to derive a construction of such rational? I do also realize my question is probably trivial.

Comment: Basically what rudin defines is a set of rational that can be represented in base $2$ with finitely many 1's. Can we just construct such rational in the following way? Between two real numbers there are infinite rationals, let's pick a rational $q$, if such rational in base $2$ has finitely many ones we are done, otherwise we just chop after some digits (disregards all the ones after some point), so we would get a rational $r < q < f(x)+\epsilon/2$. Can this be a valid argument?

Comment: Yes, it can be valid, but one needs to make an argument that one can truncate $q$ (chop off digits) in such a way that $x\in A(r)$. We need not look at the case $f(x)=1$ (though this is trivial, take $r=1$) since we only look at the case where $f(x)+f(y)<1$. Now we can assume that $\epsilon$ is so small that $f(x) + \epsilon/2 < 1$. Choose $k$ so large that $2^{-k} < \epsilon/2$. Then there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r = \frac{n}{2^k}$ lies strictly between $f(x)$ and $f(x) + \epsilon/2$. But that isn't necessary, we get a suitable $r\in D$ immediately from the definition of $\inf$.

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is the _greatest_ lower bound of $M(x) := \{ r \in D : x \in A(r)\}$, it follows that $f(x) + \epsilon/2$ is not a lower bound of $M(x)$. That means that there is an $r_0 \in M(x)$ with $r_0 < f(x) + \epsilon/2$. By definition of $M(x)$, we have $r_0 \in D$ and $x \in A(r_0)$. And thus, $r_0$ is suitable, we have $f(x) \leqslant r_0$, $r_0 \in D$, $x \in A(r_0)$, and $r_0 < f(x) + \epsilon/2$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, the result follows from the fact that $D$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and $\{A(r)\}$ is totally ordered by set inclusion.

To see that $D$ is dense in $[0,1]$, let $f(x)\in [0,1]$ be arbitrary.
Let $c_1 = 0$ if $f(x) < 1/2$ and $c_1 = 1$ if $f(x)\ge 1/2$.
Then, $f(x)\in[c_1/2,c_1/2+1/2]$.
Let $c_2 = 0$ if $f(x)<c_1/2+1/4$ and $c_2 = 1$ if $f(x) \ge c_1/2+1/4$.
Then, $f(x)\in[c_1/2+c_2/4,c_1/2+c_2/4+1/4]$.
By continuing this procedure, we can make $r = c_1/2 + c_2/4 + \cdots + c_n/2^n$ arbitrarily close to $f(x)$.

Since $D$ is dense in $[0,1]$, for every $0\le f(x)<1$ and every $\epsilon>0$, we can always find $r\in D$ satisfying $f(x) < r < f(x) + \epsilon$.
Since $f(x) = \inf\{r':x\in A(r')\}$ and $f(x) < r$, there exists $r'\in[f(x),r)$ such that $x\in A(r') \subset A(r)$.